# Implement filter functionality using react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all please have a look here.

```
[http://codepen.io/webmaster444/pen/yOxrNa][1]
```

Here you could notice that it searches names start with input but not whole names.

For instance if you input touch then it returns no value.
I want to return iPod touch.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 10 change

```
if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input)) {
```

to

```
if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) === -1) {
```

Don't rely on truthy or falsy values, do the proper conversion and use the `===` operator every time you have the slightest doubt on how a value such as an numeric value will be converted into boolean.